# Undefined reference when linking protobuf

Tags: c++, c++14, undefined-reference, protocol-buffers

I'm working on a Mac. I installed libprotobuf with `brew install protobuf --c++11`.

```
17:51 $ brew info protobuf
protobuf: stable 2.6.1 (bottled), devel 3.0.0-beta-4, HEAD
Protocol buffers (Google's data interchange format)
https://github.com/google/protobuf/
/usr/local/Cellar/protobuf/2.6.1 (149 files, 7.0M) *
  Built from source on 2016-08-02 at 17:42:15 with: --c++11
```

`libprotobuf.dylib` lives in `/usr/local/Cellar/protobuf/2.6.1/lib`.

I wrote the following dummy app hoping to invoke [this constructor](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.io.zero_copy_stream_impl_lite#StringOutputStream.StringOutputStream.details):

```
// test.cc
#include <string>
#include <google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.h>
#include <google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl_lite.h>

int main() {
  std::string s{"hello"};
  google::protobuf::io::StringOutputStream sos(&s);
}
```

When I compile the app, I get an undefined reference error:

```
17:55 $ g++ -L/usr/local/Cellar/protobuf/2.6.1/lib -std=c++14 test.cc -lprotobuf
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "google::protobuf::io::StringOutputStream::StringOutputStream(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*)", referenced from:
      _main in ccyQlDM5.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When I check the `.dylib` for `StringOutputStream`, it's a little wonky.

```
17:56 $ nm /usr/local/Cellar/protobuf/2.6.1/lib/libprotobuf.dylib | c++filt | grep "StringOutputStream(std::"
000000000000e3ac T google::protobuf::io::StringOutputStream::StringOutputStream(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*)
000000000000e398 T google::protobuf::io::StringOutputStream::StringOutputStream(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*)
```

Why is `basic_string` namespace-prefixed by `::__1` in my list of symbols for that `.dylib`? How can I fix this?

If this isn't a problem (perhaps an artifact of unmangling), why am I still receiving an undefined reference to a constructor call I know to be defined?

I'm using `gcc 5.3.0` to compile `test.cc`.

Comment: Doesn't GCC 5 have a different string type than GCC 4? You probably need a library that's compiled with GCC 5.

Comment: @KerrekSB The library was built from source (`Built from source ... with: --c++11`). Do you think it's worthwhile to avoid `brew` altogether and try to clone the standalone repo and build that?

Comment: The brew version was built with clang, which defaults to -stdlib=libc++. Gcc defaults to -stdlib=libstdc++. The two are incompatible.

Comment: @RichardHodges Ah, that explains it! I'll try to build with `gcc`. Quite a bother... :) I'll report back, but feel free to add an answer.

Comment: @RichardHodges: Ah yes, that's the other issue :-) Also, I don't think GCC has a `-stdlib` flag.

Comment: You also seem to be switching between C++11 and C++14.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Homebrew only supports building with C++11. AFAIK, it is typically _only_ built with C++11 per Makefile... but I could be wrong.

Comment: @erip: *shrug* Regardless, that's not going to work. GCC at least maintains ABI-compatibility only within standard versions.

Comment: Hence why I was trying to compile with gcc. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As referenced in the comments, Homebrew was building with `clang` instead of `g++`.

I removed the protobuf installed by `brew`, checked out and built the source, copied the new `.dylib` to `/usr/local/lib` and it worked fine.

Comment: I have to ask... why not use Xcode's clang when building on a mac?

Comment: @RichardHodges Eventually it's going to be on Linux. Trying to "black box"-ify as much as possible and just focus on the "real problems" (like linking..) :)

Comment: @RichardHodges And if nothing else, pedagogical reasons are good enough for me.

Comment: probably sensible. apple seems to have slowed down their once-excellent support for clang.